# How to get webcam images?

Tags: webcam

I'm working with C++, on Windows Vista, with the IDE--Code:Blocks.

I have attempted to get images using OpenCV, however it does not support my camera types for some reason and is super complicated to integrate different versions of it to see if they work as there are almost no tutorials on the web for this "that actually work".

Is there a simple way to get a snapshot from a camera? Why is it that my Skype is compatible with almost any webcam but OpenCV isn't?

I downloaded DirectX, but I need Visual Studio for it. Should I purchase Visual Studio and ditch Codeblocks?

Thank you!!!!!

Comment: You could take a look at Microsoft Encoder SDK. I was able to get images from a laptop webcams in .NET. Don't know if it can be used with C++ or code blocks. If you wanted to move to Visual Studio them Microsoft offer various "express" editions for free.

Comment: wow great I might just do that.

Comment: There is an example in the sdk that streams images from the first device it finds, so all you have to do is find your device with that list/array and use that.